# How I can use a jar file in Delphi for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, jar, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

to my project:

My Task is it to built a Android/IOS Application that can connect with Bluetooth a BIXOLON SPP-R200II Printer and print Strings.

My GUI:

I use Delphi AppMethod in Object PASCAL

I look on the homepage of the Printer and download the sdk. In the Folder are two jar files.

- BixolonPrinter.jar
- BixolonPrinterWithDoubleByteFontBinary.jar

Now I want use it in Delphi but I don't know how I can do this.

My Question:

How I can convert a jar file to a apk or convert to dll. so that I can use it in Delphi :P

Comment: Kind of depends what you mean by "use a jar file". Perhaps you could expand on what's in these files, and how you want to use them.

Comment: A JAR file is essentially a ZIP file containing compiled Java classes.  Think of it like Java's equivalent of Delphi's packages.  Delphi for Android uses JNI to access Java classes.